# What are the consequences if you do Abmeldung 2 weeks before?

Tags: germany, bureaucracy

I am moving out of Germany. I understand that "Deregistration shall be possible no more than one week before moving out".

I want to do Abmeldung / Deregistration 2 weeks before actual move out date to be on safe side. I am worried that I might not get appointment in the desired week or I might loose contract cancellation confirmation if I do it in last week. I feel that 1 week is insufficient time with postal mail.

Could someone share more insight on what bad can happen if I secure 1 week early Deregistration confirmation?

Comment: The consequence may be that the deregistration will not be accepted because it is not inside the '7 days before or 14 days after' timeframe.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Thanks for your reply. If I change the day of moving out by 1 or 2 day to get it within 7 days window, would it be illegal?

Comment: By signing the form you are confirming that the information is correct. If you are actually leaving before the contract ends, then that is no problem.